# Spring Cloud Config without the server

Tags: spring, system, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-config

The role of the Config Server while using Spring Cloud Config seems to be pretty dumb and hosting it seems to be an unnecessary overhead. Is there a way to get the Clients to directly read configs from the git repo?

Answer (score 1):

You can let Spring Boot look at specific locations for the config files: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

If you set this location to your cloned git repo (checked out on the branch you need) and solve the update from the origin repository, this might work.

Answer (score 0):

It is achievable via the embedding config server approach
[Do refer to Embedding The Config Server section](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_embedding_the_config_server)

`If you want to read the configuration for an application directly from the backend repository (instead of from the config server), you basically want an embedded config server with no endpoints. You can switch off the endpoints entirely by not using the @EnableConfigServer annotation (set spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true).`